# How to fix "Overlapping accesses to 'self', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable" error in my code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, swift4.2

I can't continue with my app and I can't test run it because something is wrong in my code that I don't know how to fix!
Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle() {
        if count < 2 { return }
        for i in 0..<(count - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i 
            customSwap(a: &self[i], b: &self[j])
        }
    }
}

func customSwap<T>(a: inout T, b: inout T) {
    let temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp
}
```

Comment: Swift 4.2 has a built-in shuffle() method.

Comment: If you insist on writing your own shuffle, use the built-in `swapAt` method: `self.swapAt(i, j)` instead of calling `customSwap`.

Comment: Thank a lot!! swapAt fixed the problem!! :)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that an array is a value type, and when you modify one element you change the whole array.  So your call to `customSwap()` is passing in two references to the whole array which leads to the **overlapping accesses to self** error.

Instead, you could write `customSwap()` to take one copy of the array and the indices you want to swap:

```
func customSwap<T>(_ array: inout [T], _ a: Int, _ b: Int) {
    let temp = array[a]
    array[a] = array[b]
    array[b] = temp
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
customSwap(&self, i, j)
```

---

But you don't have to do that, because `Array` has a built-in [`swapAt(_:_)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2893281-swapat) defined like this:

> ```
>  mutating func swapAt(_ i: Int, _ j: Int)
> ```

So you could replace your `customSwap` call with:

```
self.swapAt(i, j)
```

---

But `Array` has a built-in [`shuffle()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle) that you can just call instead of implementing it yourself.